# How to Remove special character from a string

Tags: php

I want to remove the following special character from my string.

```
:
'
""
`
``
```

how can i remove each of the above character from my string?

Answer (score 4):

Use str_replace:

```
$to_remove = array(':', "'", '"', '`'); // Add all the characters you want to remove here

$result = str_replace($to_remove, '', $your_string);
```

This will replace all the characters in the $to_remove array with an empty string, essentially removing them.

Comment: Good solution, but that's not php array syntax. The php way would be `$to_remove = array(':', "'", '"', '`');` But that's a minor thing.

Comment: @Cold Hawaiian - Oops! Thanks for spotting that - haven't written much php for a while! Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$string = preg_replace('/[:'" `]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, but the PHP regex functions are less efficient than str_replace.

Comment: @Cold Hawaiian You're right - but IMHO that only matters if/when his code requires optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more efficient solution than using preg_replace, which uses regular expressions:

```
$string = str_replace(array(':',"'",'"','`'), '', $sourceString);
```

You can read more about str_replace and preg_replace at the php docs:

- http://www.php.net/str_replace
- http://www.php.net/preg_replace